# Distributing wxHaskell based application in Windows

Tags: dll, haskell, wxwidgets, wxhaskell

For a wxHaskell based application distributed on Windows, can I distribute the necessary WX DLLs right alongside the application, without having to do a separate install of WX?

I want to be able to distribute the application as a zip file and not require the user to have anything installed. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm by no means a wxHaskell or a wxWidgets expert, but...

For your use case, it sounds like you want statically linked libraries, not DLLs. [WxWidgets seems to be fine with that](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_libraries.html#libraries). So if you use `ghc -static -optl-static -optl-pthread`, you should get the result you want.

Some annotation: the `-static` option isn't really necessary: it's ghc's default. The `-optl` options get passed to gcc. `-optl-static` statically links in any C libraries you're using (and I imagine wxHaskell uses some). And `-optl-pthread` is black magic to me, but it [seems like a good idea](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/blog/Some%20GHC%20notes%20for%20myself.html).